# И(,) вероятнее всего, потому

Tags: пунктуация

"Граждане тоже игнорируют эту процедуру. И(,) вероятнее всего, потому, что хлебное место терять не хочется".

Нужна ли запятая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не отделяются запятой вводные слова от союзов, стоящих в начале предложения: И действительно, он скоро уехал; А между прочим, магазин уже был закрыт; И в самом деле, послышались голоса внизу (Ч.); И пожалуй, он правильно поступил [справочник п\р Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=24)

Запятую после И ставить не  нужно: *И вероятнее всего, потому....*

Answer (score 1):

И вероятнее всего потому, что хлебное место терять не хочется.

Нет необходимости в большом количестве запятых,  "вероятнее всего" в данном случае  является не вводным словом, а выполняет функцию наречия:

ПРИМЕРЫ

"Так вот человек и животное в течение зимы сближались между собой все тесней и тесней, вероятнее всего потому, что оба по-своему были так одиноки (М. М. Пришвин).

"Но так не выходило, вероятнее всего потому, что кругом шла чужая жизнь, а разнообразие умственных и художественных впечатлений мешало сосредоточиться на сильном замысле в драме или в комедии" (П. Д. Боборыкин).

Comment: "Вероятнее всего" в Ваших примерах тоже вводное сочетание, оно не выделяется запятыми только потому, что стоит в начале придаточного предложения (после главного и запятой). А в нашем предложении структура другая.

Comment: Не имеет значения, эти же предложения можно перестроить так, чтобы в начале был присоединительный союз. Надо понимать, что вводность - это синтаксическая функция, и для выражения "вероятнее всего" здесь больше подходит не функция вводного слова, а функция наречия. Вот, к примеру, слово "вероятно" наречием быть не может, а может быть только вводным словом или сказуемым, и здесь уж придется обособлять его как вводное слово.

Comment: Без запятых возникает вопрос "Что вероятнее всего?". А ответа в контексте нет.

Comment: Кстати, в начале придаточного вводное должно обособляться. Просто это примеры с устаревшей пунктуацией. Нормативного оправдания у них нет.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь запятая нужна! 
Иногда (при интонационным выделении вводных слов или предложений, при их включении в текст посредством ***подчинительного союза**)*** после присоединительного союза запятая перед вводной конструкцией ставится: *Но, к великой моей досаде, ***Швабрин... решительно  объявил, **что** песня моя нехороша (П.); И***, как водится,***вспоминали только одно хорошее (Крым.).*

***Справочник-практикум, стр. 212, пункт 6. Розенталь. Д. Э.***